# using const generic in implementation of trait for another trait causes "unconstrained const parameter" error

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to implement some abstract linear algebra traits and structs as part of my practices learning rust. In the code below when I implement `VectorAbstract<TValue>` for `VectorDynamic<TValue>` there's no problem; but when I try to do the same for `VectorStatic<TValue, DIM_COUNT>` I get the following error :

```
the const parameter `DIM_COUNT` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
unconstrained const parameter
note: expressions using a const parameter must map each value to a distinct output value
note: proving the result of expressions other than the parameter are unique is not supported
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
What's the correct way to implement this ?
Here's my code :

```
pub trait VectorAbstract<TValue: Scalar>: VectorSpaceElement + // a dozen std traits
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue;
}

pub trait VectorDynamic<TValue: Scalar>: VectorAbstract<TValue> {
    fn dim_count(&self) -> usize;
    fn from_list(arr: Vec<TValue>) -> Self;
}

pub trait VectorStatic<TValue: Scalar, const DIM_COUNT: usize>: VectorAbstract<TValue> {
    fn from_array(arr: [TValue; DIM_COUNT]) -> Self;
}

impl<TValue: Scalar, TVector: VectorDynamic<TValue>> VectorAbstract<TValue> for TVector {
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        // ... dot product body for dynamic vectors ...
    }
}

impl<TValue: Scalar, const DIM_COUNT: usize, TVector: VectorStatic<TValue, DIM_COUNT>>
    VectorAbstract<TValue> for TVector
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        // ... dot product body for static vectors ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried the following :

```
pub trait VectorStatic<TValue: Scalar>: VectorAbstract<TValue> {
    const DIM_COUNT: usize;
    fn from_array(arr: [TValue; Self::DIM_COUNT]) -> Self;
}
impl<TValue: Scalar, TVector: VectorStatic<TValue>> VectorAbstract<TValue> for TVector {
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        // ... dot product body for static vectors ...
    }
}
```

But I get the following error where I'm declaring the `from_array` function :

```
generic parameters may not be used in const operations  
cannot perform const operation using `Self`  
note: type parameters may not be used in const expressions
```

Note : I want the DIM_COUNT to be obtained in compile time somehow, so no `fn dim_count()` for `VectorStatic`.

**UPDATE 2**

Also when I completely remove the implementation for VectorStatic, I get another error in another file where I have a `Vector2` struct and try to implement `VectorStatic<TValue, 2>` for that:

```
pub struct Vector2<TValue: Scalar> {
    pub x: TValue,
    pub y: TValue,
}
impl<TValue: Scalar> VectorStatic<TValue, 2> for Vector2<TValue> {
    // ... implementation ...
}
```

And here's the error :

```
the trait bound `math::algebra::vectors::vector2::Vector2<TValue>: math::algebra::abstractions::VectorDynamic<TValue>` is not satisfied
the trait `math::algebra::abstractions::VectorDynamic<TValue>` is not implemented for `math::algebra::vectors::vector2::Vector2<TValue>`
```

Note that this Vector2 struct is not supposed to be a `VectorDynamic` at all.
There's definitely something I have not understood clearly here, maybe rust thinks I'm trying to make every `VectorAbstract` a `VectorDynamic` or something like that ?
What is it that I'm missing ?

**UPDATE 3**

Perhaps I should also mention that I already tried the following :

```
impl<TValue: Scalar> VectorAbstract<TValue> for dyn VectorDynamic<TValue>
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        // ... dot product body for dynamic vectors ...
    }
}
impl<TValue: Scalar, const DIM_COUNT: usize> VectorAbstract<TValue> for dyn VectorStatic<TValue, DIM_COUNT>
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        // ... dot product body for static vectors ...
    }
}
```

But in that case I get this error for both :

```
the trait `math::algebra::abstractions::VectorDynamic/VectorStatic` cannot be made into an object
```

and then a dozen lines that say because they used `Self` as a type parameter.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal stripped-down example that still reproduces the error? When I paste your code to the playground, I get a number of different errors, ranging from incorrect order of type/const parameters to traits like `Scalar` and `VectorSpaceElement` missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that there are no guarantees that a type `TVector` will only implement `VectorStatic<TValue, 1>` and not implement `VectorStatic<TValue, 2>` which would give conflicting implementations of `VectorAbstract<TValue>`.

Update 1 is the way to go, since that way a type cannot implement `VectorStatic` more than once. Currently this requires nightly rust with `#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]` added at the start of `lib.rs`/`main.rs`

The next problem will be the 2 `impl`-s of `VectorAbstract<TValue>`. Again there is nothing to guarantee that `TVector` does not implement both `VectorDynamic<TValue>` and `VectorStatic<TValue>` which would give conflicting implementations of `VectorAbstarct<TValue>`. As far as I know this cannot be done even with unstable features. The best way do it is to use wrapper structs.

`VectorStatic1` + `VectorStaticWrapper1` requires the added feature and works only in nightly rust version, `VectorStatic2` + `VectorStaticWrapper2` works in stable.

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub trait Scalar {}

pub trait VectorAbstract<TValue: Scalar>: 
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue;
}

pub trait VectorDynamic<TValue: Scalar>: VectorAbstract<TValue> {
    fn dim_count(&self) -> usize;
    fn from_list(arr: Vec<TValue>) -> Self;
}

pub trait VectorStatic1<TValue: Scalar>: VectorAbstract<TValue> {
    const DIM_COUNT: usize;
    fn from_array(arr: [TValue; Self::DIM_COUNT]) -> Self;
}

pub trait VectorStatic2<TValue: Scalar, const DIM_COUNT: usize>: VectorAbstract<TValue> {
    fn from_array(arr: [TValue; DIM_COUNT]) -> Self;
}

struct VectorDynamicWrapper<T>(T);
struct VectorStaticWrapper1<T>(T);
struct VectorStaticWrapper2<T, const DIM_COUNT: usize>(T);

impl<TValue: Scalar, TVector: VectorDynamic<TValue>> VectorAbstract<TValue> for VectorDynamicWrapper<TVector> {
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        let lhs = &lhs.0;
        let rhs = &rhs.0;
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<TValue: Scalar, TVector: VectorStatic1<TValue>>
    VectorAbstract<TValue> for VectorStaticWrapper1<TVector>
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        let lhs = &lhs.0;
        let rhs = &rhs.0;
        let dim_count = TVector::DIM_COUNT;
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<TValue: Scalar, const DIM_COUNT: usize, TVector: VectorStatic2<TValue, DIM_COUNT>>
    VectorAbstract<TValue> for VectorStaticWrapper2<TVector, DIM_COUNT>
{
    fn dot(lhs: &Self, rhs: &Self) -> TValue {
        let lhs = &lhs.0;
        let rhs = &rhs.0;
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to constraint a type that implements VectorStatic not to implement VectorDynamic, or the other way around ?

Comment: Not the way you would want it to. There is the `negative_impls` feature in nightly rust but that still does not allow the 2 generic `impl<T> VectorStatic for T {}`-s.