# How to implement iterator for array [Option<f64>; N] with N elements

Tags: arrays, rust, iterator

I have several structures with N (can be distinct) fields of type `Option<f64>`. I want with a single function to evaluate whether or not I keep small values (values ​​< DELTA = 0.005) ​​of these fields. For this, I must implement an iterator that captures only the desired N fields from the structures.

Let KeysValuesA and KeysValuesB be structures defined with distinct numbers of fields of type `Option<f64>` (N is equal to 3 and 4 respectively):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Clone)]
struct KeysValuesA {
    key_a : String,
    key_b : u32,
    key_c : Option<u16>,
    value_a: Option<f64>,
    value_b: Option<f64>,
    value_c: Option<f64>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Clone)]
struct KeysValuesB {
    key_a : String,
    key_b : Option<u16>,
    value_a: Option<f64>,
    value_b: Option<f64>,
    value_c: Option<f64>,
    value_d: Option<f64>,
}
```

After implementing the trait:

```rust
trait AllValues {
    fn all_values_vec(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut Option<f64>>;
    fn all_values_arr<const N: usize>(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; N];
}

impl AllValues for KeysValuesA {

    fn all_values_vec(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut Option<f64>> {
        let values: Vec<&mut Option<f64>> = vec![
            &mut self.value_a,
            &mut self.value_b,
            &mut self.value_c,
        ];
        values
    }

    fn all_values_arr<const N: usize>(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; N] { todo!() }
}

impl AllValues for KeysValuesB {

    fn all_values_vec(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut Option<f64>> {
        let values: Vec<&mut Option<f64>> = vec![
            &mut self.value_a,
            &mut self.value_b,
            &mut self.value_c,
            &mut self.value_d,
        ];
        values
    }

    fn all_values_arr<const N: usize>(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; N] { todo!() }
}
```

I use the iterator for the function, like that (DELTA is a constant):

```
fn despise_small_values_vec<T: AllValues>(keysvalues: &mut T) {

    for value in keysvalues.all_values_vec() {
        if value.unwrap_or(0.0).abs() < DELTA {
            *value = None;
        }
    }
}
```

So I can implement iterator from Output: `Vec<&mut Option<f64>>`, but I cannot implement it from Output: array `[&mut Option<f64>; N]`.

How to implement iterator for array `[&mut Option<f64>; N]` such that N can vary according to the Struct used?

And what would be the advantage of using array instead of using vector?

Follow the codes: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0dc41dc58955d0b3bbdb3c80c3c0d144)

Comment: It's odd to ask how useful is a function that *you* implement for a usage *we* don't know anything of. As far as I know, there is no point in having a `[&mut Option<f64>; N]` here instead of a vector, but who knows, maybe *you* need it?

Comment: `N` shouldn't be a generic parameter, but instead it should be an associated constant as in `VectorStatic1` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134403/5397009). Note however that this feature is not yet available in stable Rust and requires the nightly compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly some odd code... but I think you just need to make the trait itself generic over `N`, not `all_values_arr`. A generic argument means "the caller is free to choose any value of the generic that *they* see fit", which is not what you want; it's up to you, not the caller, how many items one of these structs has.

```rust
trait AllValues<const N: usize> {
    fn all_values_arr(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; N];
    fn all_values_vec(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut Option<f64>> {
        self.all_values_arr().into()
    }
}

impl AllValues<3> for KeysValuesA {
    fn all_values_arr(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; 3] {
        [&mut self.value_a, &mut self.value_b, &mut self.value_c]
    }
}

impl AllValues<4> for KeysValuesB {
    fn all_values_arr(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; 4] {
        [
            &mut self.value_a,
            &mut self.value_b,
            &mut self.value_c,
            &mut self.value_d,
        ]
    }
}

fn despise_small_values_vec<const N: usize, T: AllValues<N>>(keysvalues: &mut T) {
    const DELTA: f64 = 1e-10;
    for value in keysvalues.all_values_arr() {
        if value.unwrap_or(0.0).abs() < DELTA {
            *value = None;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut kv = KeysValuesB {
        key_a: "a".into(),
        key_b: Some(1),
        value_a: Some(1.0),
        value_b: Some(1e-20),
        value_c: Some(-1e-20),
        value_d: None,
    };
    println!("{:#?}", kv);
    despise_small_values_vec(&mut kv);
    println!("{:#?}", kv);
}
```

Prints:

```
KeysValuesB {
    key_a: "a",
    key_b: Some(
        1,
    ),
    value_a: Some(
        1.0,
    ),
    value_b: Some(
        1e-20,
    ),
    value_c: Some(
        -1e-20,
    ),
    value_d: None,
}
KeysValuesB {
    key_a: "a",
    key_b: Some(
        1,
    ),
    value_a: Some(
        1.0,
    ),
    value_b: None,
    value_c: None,
    value_d: None,
}
```

Comment: But still, this variant will now work for functions like `despise_small_values_vec<T: AllValues>(keysvalues: &mut T)` because we still need to specify the number of elements

Comment: @PavloMyroniuk See my edit

Comment: Great solution presented by [ballpointben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496433/ballpointben). See the code: [Solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad6a1bc91abb72fcdba2c6058c539239). But, what would be the advantage of using array instead of using vector?

Comment: Cool, I like it. Upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `all_values_arr` using `Vec` and then cast it to the array. Like this:

```rust
impl AllValues for KeysValuesB {
    fn all_values_arr<const N: usize>(&mut self) -> [&mut Option<f64>; N] {
        debug_assert_eq!(4, N);
        
        vec![
            &mut self.value_a,
            &mut self.value_b,
            &mut self.value_c,
            &mut self.value_d,
        ].try_into().unwrap()
    }
}
```

It compiles and works, but there is a huge inconvenience: for each `all_values_arr` call, you need to specify the `N`. Example:

```rust
keysvalues.all_values_arr::<4>(); // but you don't know exactly how many values keysvalues contain
```

Also, you can try to do it using associated constants but it also will not work because const generics require `const context` and associated constants are not const.

So using the `Vec` is the most convenience way in your situation.